# drgrid not rendering unless cache is cleared

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a rather large dojo project in which I am using dgrid to display data from local storage. *Some* of the drgids do not render unless the browser cache is cleared first. This manifests itself in IE10 and Chrome but not Safara. There are no JS errors. Anyone run into this before?

This what it looks like when its not working
[image]

This is when its working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was not waiting to be sure the DOM was ready. So sometimes it works and sometimes it didn't. Sheepish grin.